# So is string object type or primitive type?

Tags: javascript

From JavaScript: The Definitive Guide by David Flanagan

> JavaScript types can be divided into two categories: primitive types
>   and object types. JavaScript’s primitive types include numbers,
>   strings of text (known as strings), and Boolean truth values (known as
>   booleans).

It states that the `string` is primitive type. But later on there was an example code

```
var s = "hello, world" // Start with some text.
s.charAt(0) // => "h": the first character.
s.charAt(s.length-1) // => "d": the last character.
s.substring(1,4) // => "ell": the 2nd, 3rd and 4th characters.
s.slice(1,4) // => "ell": same thing
s.slice(-3) // => "rld": last 3 characters
s.indexOf("l") // => 2: position of first letter l.
s.lastIndexOf("l") // => 10: position of last letter l.
s.indexOf("l", 3) // => 3: position of first "l" at or after 3
```

So is string object type or primitive? how can a primitive type have methods? Isn't this object type property? If it's some kind of hybrid of both, then when it is primitive and when it is object?

Comment: Keep reading, you'll find the explanation on your own. Also this is not a question you should ask on SO, since you have no problem with your code, just a lack of understanding of the language.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Primitve types can also have got methods like object types. But you can not assign new methods/properties to literal primitive types but you can assign new methods/properties to literal object types. That's one difference between primitves and objects.

Comment: From @nicael's link, you can even skip directly to [Distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are primitive values:

> [**4.3.2 primitive value**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2)
>
> member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, or String

But there are also string objects, which are objects and not primitives:

> [**4.3.18 String object**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.18)
>
> member of the Object type that is an instance of the standard built-in
>   `String` constructor

It may seem primitive strings have properties, but no.

When you use for example `string.charAt(0)`, a string object is created with the same value as your primitive string. This object inherits from `String.prototype`. The `charAt` method of this string object is called, and the returned value is returned in `string.charAt(0)`. Then the string object is removed.

When you assign a property to a primitive string, something similar happens: the property is assigned to the new string object instead of to the primitive.

Some examples:

```
var primitiveStr = 'foo',
    objectStr = new String('foo');
typeof primitiveStr; // 'string'
typeof objectStr; // 'object'
typeof primitiveStr.charAt; // 'function'
typeof objectStr.charAt; // 'function'
primitiveStr.foo = objectStr.foo = 123;
typeof primitiveStr.foo; // 'undefined'
typeof objectStr.foo; // 'number'
```